# How to make android respond if one Edittext is empty and the other isn't?

Tags: java, android

How do I make Android display a Toast if one Edittext is empty and the other isn't?

The code so far

```
if (sPassword.matches(sPassword2)) {
    Context finished = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence registered = "You have been Registered!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast wrong = Toast.makeText(finished, registered, duration);
    wrong.show();

    startActivity(finish);
} else {
    nomatch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unmatched);
    nomatch.setText("Passwords do not match");
    nomatch.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    Context unmatched = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence improper = "Passwords do not match";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast noMatch = Toast.makeText(unmatched, improper, duration);
    noMatch.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is

```
if (sPassword.equals("") && (!sPassword2.equals(""))) {

    // that means your sPassword edit text is empty and sPassword2 is not empty.
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked and is lightweight too!

Comment: Notice for NullPointerException if sPasswords are null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sPassword.gettext().tostring().trim().equals("") || sPassword2.gettext().tostring().trim().equals("")) {

    // It will enter here even if one of them is empty
}
```

Comment: This response would be even better if accompanied by a few words of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty() || sPassword2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ADD YOUR MESSAGE HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: This response would be even better if accompanied by a few words of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @Moubeen Farooq Warar answer: You should check "" to equal like this:

```
if("".equals(sPassword)&&(!"".equals(sPassword2))){

  // it will not couse NullPointerException
 }
```